# I need to fetch all users email of a particular group using AD in .net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I know there are lots of methods already given in stackoverflow but in my case all of them taking too long time. I post a method which takes less time but still it is too long to implement. Please help me so that it takes less execution time. Also take consideration that i am using .net 2.0 framework.

```
        try
        {
            List<string> lstEmails = new List<string>();
            string filter1 = string.Format("(anr={0})", "groupname");
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            searcher.Filter = filter1;
            searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
            IEnumerable res = (IEnumerable)searcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry().Invoke("members");
            //IEnumerable<string> rest = (IEnumerable<string>)res;

            if (res != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    foreach (IEnumerable resl in res)
                    {
                        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                        DirectoryEntry dr = new DirectoryEntry(resl);
                        string strEmail = null;
                        if (dr.Properties["mail"].Value != null)
                        {
                            strEmail = dr.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(strEmail);
                            DateTime stop = DateTime.Now;
                            Console.WriteLine((stop - start).TotalMinutes.ToString());
                            index++;
                            Console.WriteLine(index.ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strEmail))
                        {
                            // groupMemebers.Add("sam",strEmail);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }


        }
        catch { }
```

This is your suggested method Daro..

```
    DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domain, "domainname" + strLDAPUserName, strLDAPPassword);
        DomainController controller = DomainController.FindOne(context);
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}",controller.Domain), strLDAPUserName, strLDAPPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
List<string> userList = new List<string>();  
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;   
        using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(entry)) 
        {
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");  
            ds.PageSize = 10000;
            string DistingushiedName = "CN=" + groupName + ",OU=Users,dc=CompanyName,dc=com";
            ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:="+DistingushiedName+"))";   
            ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree; 
            try 
            {
                foreach (SearchResult user in ds.FindAll())   
                {
                    try  
                    {
                        userList.Add(user.Path);//.Properties["mail"][0].ToString()); 
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)    
                    {
                        throw new Exception(E.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception E)    
            {
                throw new Exception(E.Message); 
            }
            DateTime EndTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan Dif = EndTime.Subtract(StartTime);
        }
```

Comment: you can use principal context to fetch the email id . It is easy and fast too. If you want I can show you here example

Comment: @Rahul  As par my knowledge principal context is supported by .net 3.5 onwards. I mentioned that i am using .net 2.0. If that can be used in .net 2.0 then please explain it with an example. Thanks

Comment: yes it is only supported by .Net 3.5. DirectoryEntry is the only option otherwise.

Comment: could you tell me any way so this queries will have less execution time

Comment: You need to only fetch Email Address of all the members or of a single member?

Comment: All the members belongs to that group. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey this is the correct way...

```
  try
        {
            List<string> ReturnArray = new List<string>();
            DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domainName, domainName + "\\" + UserName, Password);
            DomainController controller = DomainController.FindOne(context);
            string LDAPAddress = string.Format("LDAP://{0}", controller.Domain);
            DirectoryEntry deDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPAddress, UserName, Password);
            deDirEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(deDirEntry);
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            string sFilter = String.Format("(&(objectcategory=group)(cn=" + GroupName + "))");

            mySearcher.Filter = sFilter;
            mySearcher.Sort.Direction = SortDirection.Ascending;
            mySearcher.Sort.PropertyName = "cn";
            SearchResult result;
            DirectoryEntry ResultEntry;
            result = mySearcher.FindOne();
            ResultEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
            GroupName = ResultEntry.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
            mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(deDirEntry);
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
            sFilter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=person)(memberOf={0}))", GroupName);
            mySearcher.Filter = sFilter;
            mySearcher.Sort.Direction = SortDirection.Ascending;
            mySearcher.Sort.PropertyName = "cn";
            SearchResultCollection results;
            results = mySearcher.FindAll();
            foreach (SearchResult resEnt in results)
            {
                ResultPropertyCollection propcoll = resEnt.Properties;
                foreach (string key in propcoll.PropertyNames)
                {
                    if (key == "mail")
                    {
                        foreach (object values in propcoll[key])
                        {
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(values.ToString()))
                            {
                                ReturnArray.Add(values.ToString());
                                Console.WriteLine(values.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return ReturnArray;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Thanks everyone for your valuable suggesstion

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:-

```
string[] email = new string[0];

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Users,dc=me,dc=com", username, password);
string groupName = "GroupName";//Group NAme

DirectorySearcher groupSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
groupSearch.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + groupName + ")";
groupSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
SearchResult groupResult = groupSearch.FindOne(); // getting the members who belongs to the concern groupname

if (groupResult != null)
 {
    email = new string[groupResult.Properties["member"].Count];  //creatign an array to store all the email address
    for (int iSearchLoop = 0; iSearchLoop < groupResult.Properties["member"].Count; iSearchLoop++)
      {
         string userName = groupResult.Properties["member"][iSearchLoop].ToString();
         int index = userName.IndexOf(',');
         userName = userName.Substring(0, index).Replace("CN=", "").ToString(); // the name of the user will be fetched.

         DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
         search.Filter = "(name=" + userName + ")";
         search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
         SearchResult result = search.FindOne(); //finding the mail id
         if (result != null)
          {
            email[iSearchLoop] = result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString(); //assigning the mail id to an array....
          }
      }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I need to find all user email belongs to a particular group. Please help me with some example.

Comment: No it takes around 4.5 sec to find a single user email. In that ways if the result set caontains 800 users then it will takes around 36mins that is too long.. to implement. Thanks

Comment: May I know how you are calculating the time ?

Comment: I don't know what you have used,if it is taking 4.5 sec for a single user then there must be a problem with in your **Intranet Speed**. You need to check how your organisation network is managed.

Comment: Yes i am using console application i take a time after the start of for loop and at end and then take a difference..

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough (if your AD is 2003 R2 or higher):

```
        List<string> userList = new List<string>();
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry ("GC://DC=YourDomain,DC=com")))
        {
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
            ds.PageSize = 10000;
            ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=YOUR_GROUP'S DN))";
            ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            try
            {
                foreach (SearchResult user in ds.FindAll())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        userList.Add(user.Path);//.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(E.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception E) 
            {
                throw new Exception(E.Message);
            }
            DateTime EndTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan Dif = EndTime.Subtract(StartTime);

        }
```

Replace YOUR_GROUP'S DN with the distiguished name of your group...

`memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=` is the "new" LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN operator, and retrieves all group members.  Look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914828/en-us) to see if your AD is ready and get more information.

Edit:

I gave you an answer, but an explanation might help further.

In general you should avoid ANR searches because they expand to large wildcard OR queries. Use them only if you have no idea which property contains the name you are searching for. They are **much** slower than explicit AND searches.

Secondly if you have more than one domain, you should turn off referral chasing unless you want to search through all domains until you get a hit.  In this case it would be better to do a GC:// than a LDAP:// search to find the object you’re looking for, than do an LDAP search on that object.  Depending on what you are looking for the GC query could well be enough

Edit 2:

Modified the code to give more error information and get the user path instead of E-Mail.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment.. I want to asked "YOUR_GROUP'S DN" means group distingusihed name or group name. In any case i am not getting any result. The value of ds.count is zero. Please Help

Comment: The Distinguished name is (somthing like)  CN=YourGroupName,OU=Users,dc=me,dc=com.  Do not add LDAP://!

Comment: It's just part of a fictitious path and assumes you have a group in an OU named Users.  But never mind. I modified the post.  Please have a look to see if userList is being filled, or if you are getting exceptions.  Also note that the searcher definition has been changed and needs your information.

Comment: Please take a look at my code that may help you to identify the problem

Comment: That looks correct assuming that the DN is correct.what about (DirectoryContextType.Domain, domain, "domainname" + strLDAPUserName, strLDAPPassword);   I believe that ""domainname" +" is too much.  The rest worked fine in my environment.  I am assuming that you, your computer and the DC are in the same domain...

Comment: No my system and DC had different domain. I am providing the correct group name no issue with that but still not able to fecth any records. But using string filter1 = string.Format("(CN={0})", group); filter criteria i am able to fecth results. Please tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: Start Visual Studio as a user in the DC's domain.  Than paste the code above, modify, and test.